# Wrapping a chain of AJAX requests within a function - Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chain of two AJAX requests within a forEach() loop, the second relying on the firsts response. I want to reuse this block of code, but when I wrap it within a function it no longer works. I'm new to Javascript so need all the help I can get!
Below is the code before it's wrapped in a function (it works fine)...

```
channels.forEach(function (channel) {
    $.getJSON("URL" + channel)
    .then(function (data) {
        if (data.stream !== null) {
            return "stuff";
        }
        else {
            return "other stuff";
        }
    })
    .then(function (returnedStuff) {
        $.getJSON("OtherURL" + channel)
        .done(function loadData(data) {
            //...Append data to DOM
        });
    });
});
```

And below is the section of code I want to reuse inside a function named reuse...

```
channels.forEach(function (channel) {
    function reuse() {
        $.getJSON("URL" + channel)
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data.stream !== null) {
                return "stuff";
            }
            else {
                return "other stuff";
            }
        })
        .then(function (returnedStuff) {
            $.getJSON("OtherURL" + channel)
            .done(function loadData(data) {
                //...Append data to DOM
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! It's nice to see a well-written, clear question. with the minimal code required to create the issue / question (well formatted, even!)  Thank you!

Comment: @cale_b: Makes a change today, eh? :-)

Comment: @cale_b Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

1. Move `reuse` out of the `forEach` (so you can reuse it)
2. Declare a `channel` parameter for it
3. Pass it into the `forEach`

Like this:

```
function reuse(channel) {
    $.getJSON("URL" + channel)
        .then(function(data) {
            if (data.stream !== null) {
                return "stuff";
            }
            else {
                return "other stuff";
            }
        })
        .then(function(returnedStuff) {
            $.getJSON("OtherURL" + channel)
                .done(function loadData(data) {
                    //...Append data to DOM
                });
        });
}
channels.forEach(reuse);
```

---

Side note: Function *declarations* don't need `;` after them. `;` is a statement terminator. (But it's harmless.)

Comment: I've just written in a .fail() function for the second AJAX request. When the request fails it runs the .fail() function as expected. However when the request is successful it runs both the .done() and .fail() function. Do you know why?

Comment: @OllyB: `getJSON` definitely doesn't trigger both `done` and `fail` on a successful request. But if you're using `catch` and `then`, and you handle `catch` first, you could be converting the failure into success (with the `catch`). If you can't figure out what's going on, post a new question with an [mcve] for that.